# python2.7 : i % 10 == 0 does not work

Tags: python-2.7

```
from __future__ import print_function 
i = 0
for i in range (0, 100)
  print(i, end = " ")
  i += 1 
  if i % 10 == 0 
    print(" ")
print()
```

I just start my python learning several days ago.
It is about the for_loop training.

As my codes tell, it should print out numbers from 0 to 98 increasing by 2 till 98. As 10 digits printed out, it should print another 10 digits in the next line and keep going on. But it do not work properly. However, it works from changing function to

> range(0,100) `

[range(0,100)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QnWH.png)

But do not work when I change the function to

> range(0, 100, 2)`

[range(0, 100, 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gC7e2.png)

Comment: That's because the last number generated is `98`. By incrementing it is `99`, but `99 % 10` is **not** 0.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: When you use range(0, 100, 2), i is always even and i += 1 would make it odd, hence never satisfying i % 10 == 0. Try using different variable for digit counter or modifying the operands for addition and modulus.